# HttpClient executeMethod throws java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-commons-httpclient

I have a java program which creates multiple threads where each thread makes POST request. It works fine most of the time but under heavy load it throws Connection reset exception. For example, when I made 40 simultaneous requests, couple of time I got Connection reset exception.

```
Caught: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:
   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:105
   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.
   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMetho
   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodB
   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.j
   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(Htt
   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMe
   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
   at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
```

In my Java code, I am creating an instance of HttpClient

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

The problem does not happen when I make one request wait for it to finish and then make another request. However, the moment I turn the program into multi-threading I get this issue.

Could anyone please point out how could I prevent this exception and then retry again. From google, I found out the answer may be along the lines of using

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.IdleConnectionTimeoutThread
```

I am trying to use this in the mean time but any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is there any logging server side which might give you a clue as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend either using a `MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` if you're using HttpClient 3 or `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` if you're using HttpClient 4.

I'm fairly confident that the default connection manager for both HttpClient 3 and HttpClient 4 are expecting only single thread access.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to use MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager and that solved the issue of Connection reset. I want to vote for your answer but unfortunately I don't have 15 reputation.

Comment: I think you should be able to accept the answer though.  Glad it worked out.  :)